# symfony 2 many-to-many relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to realize a many-to-many relationship between two tables.

this is my configuration:

```
Mailer\EmpfaengerBundle\Entity\Empfaenger:
  type: entity
  table: empfaenger
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    vorname:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
    nachname:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
    created_by:
      type: integer
    updated_by:
      type: integer
  manyToMany:
    verteiler:
      targetEntity: Verteiler
      mappedBy: empfaenger

Mailer\EmpfaengerBundle\Entity\Verteiler:
  type: entity
  table: verteiler
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
    created_by:
      type: integer
    updated_by:
      type: integer
  manyToMany:
    empfaenger:
      targetEntity: Empfaenger
      inversedBy: verteiler
      joinTable:
        name: verteiler_sys
        joinColumns:
          verteiler_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          empfaenger_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
```

Now when I try to edit an entry, it works in the "verteiler" table, but not in the empfaenger table.
The form is shown in the "empfaenger" edit page and the entries are highlightet, but when i change ohne, it won't save the changes.

I tried various different configurations according to the doctrine documentation but always get the same result :-(

both entities have exactly the same structure:

```
/**
     * Add empfaenger
     *
     * @param \Mailer\EmpfaengerBundle\Entity\Empfaenger $empfaenger
     * @return Verteiler
     */
    public function addEmpfaenger(\Mailer\EmpfaengerBundle\Entity\Empfaenger $empfaenger)
    {
        $this->empfaenger[] = $empfaenger;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove empfaenger
     *
     * @param \Mailer\EmpfaengerBundle\Entity\Empfaenger $empfaenger
     */
    public function removeEmpfaenger(\Mailer\EmpfaengerBundle\Entity\Empfaenger $empfaenger)
    {
        $this->empfaenger->removeElement($empfaenger);
    }

    /**
     * Get empfaenger
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getEmpfaenger()
    {
        return $this->empfaenger;
    }

and help would be appreciated.
```

Comment: the code seems to be correct. you are talking about problems when trying to store objects if i understood you right. did you update the schema via `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`?

Comment: yes i did that. and the database seems to be correct, and like i said, both entities look exactly the same, also the controllers. but it only works in one direction. if i switch the yml configuration (so that it's the other way around) it works the other way around...

Answer (score 0):

all right, i found a solution, in case anybody faces this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPrgoe3Jrjw